# Unable to write data to the transport connection Error while sending data via Socket in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to Broadcast data to my FrontEnd Applications using C# but I'm getting this error.

Here is my code looks like.

```
          Socket socket = new Socket(
              AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
              SocketType.Stream, 
              ProtocolType.Tcp
           );
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 15001));
            socket.Listen(10);
            socket.SendTimeout = 50000000;
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 50000000;
            socket.SendBufferSize = 1048510;
            socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 1048510;
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
            socket.NoDelay = true;

              var acceptedCoonection =  socket.Accept();

            // get the network stream from the accepted connection
            var stream = new NetworkStream(acceptedCoonection);

            while (acceptedCoonection.Connected )
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Transmitting Feed ..");
                try
                {
                    var JSON_DATA = PrepareMarkertDataToJSON(data);
                    stream.Write(JSON_DATA, 0, JSON_DATA.Length);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                //socketInformation.Close();
            }
            socketInformation.Listen();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Connection .....");
```

Here is how my Console Looks like

> Transmitting Feed ..
>
> Transmitting Feed ..
>
> Transmitting Feed ..
>
> Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established
> connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

It runs 3 times but the fourth time it fails. Funny enough, on my frontend there is no data even when the console writes Transmitting.

I have tried solutions to questions with a similar problem but Still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you considered using [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr)? Nicer than messing with sockets in my opinion. Just a thought.

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: How can you be sure that the frontend is flawless? Was it working correctly in the past?